# IncrediBuild configure build order

Tags: c++, visual-studio, incredibuild

I have a solution with multiple projects in it. From those numerous projects some depend on the Libs projects and the test projects depend on the code, obviously.

How do I configure IncrediBuild to build Libs first, then build code and only then proceed to building tests?

I have:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.9.40
- IncrediBuild Version 9.5.0 (build 3385)

Comment: Have you configured the dependencies in the solution ?

Comment: @RichardCritten, oh, so the IncredyBuild doesn't really matter in this case. It is MS Visual Studio configuration.

Comment: Have you tried to build Libs individually to get the lib files?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT this is exactly what am I doing and what annoys me greatly. I don't want to be forced to build them manually one by one every time I want to rebuild a project. I switch branches often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened `Project -> Project Dependencies...` went over every project and configured the code to depend on Libs and Tests to depend on the code projects and now they are built in the correct order and I don't have to go over every Lib and build/rebuid it every time I pull a minute change in it from the repository.

In the end the answer wasn't related to IncrediBuild at all, just Visual Studio functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I tested using  `build/rebuild solution` to build both the library and the project code at the same time in Visual Studio. Libs don't need to be built manually one by one and it works fine after modifying the code.